# Batch File Troubleshooting

Tags: batch-file

any suggestion for troubleshooting the following batch file.
I did add show messages and I did see the first and second message
After the second message nothing happens - no error message no more show messages from the batch file.
I verified the accounts rights on the destination server - it has full control. 
Any suggestion would  be greatly appreciated.   THANK YOU !!!
Here is the code:

```
start "" /wait cmd /c "echo In Rename Script & echo(&pause"
:: Create the new filename
set tdtd=none
set ttrn=none
set hour=none

:: get the date and time and then into single variable
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set tdtd=%%k%%i%%j
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set ttrn=%%i%%j

:: get hour If it is less than 10 left pad the hour with a zero
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%h in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set hour=%%h

start "" /wait cmd /c "echo ABC & echo(&pause"

if %hour% LSS 10 
     (set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%0%ttrn%.csv) 
else (set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%%ttrn%.csv)

start "" /wait cmd /c "echo XYZ & echo(&pause"
copy /Y "\\FileName.csv" %tufn%
start "" /wait cmd /c "echo 123 & echo(&pause"
:END
```

Comment: I am a little confused on how you are showing the messages and waiting for a pause. Are you opening a new command line window and doing the pause in the new window? If so, you can do the pause directly in the file. Just use `echo XYZ` and on the next line use `pause`. Try putting those lines in the file and it may work.

Comment: Hi Eric - the ABC message is the last one that shows - nothing else happens after that - no error message , no XYZ message on the screen - it seems to get stuck on the    if %hour% LSS 10 
     (set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%0%ttrn%.csv) 
else (set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%%ttrn%.csv)
 statement - and does not execute it - but no error message gets displayed either.

Comment: You shouldn't need all those start commands. You should be able to just use echo on its own. Also, move that `do set ttrn=%%i%%j` back to after the `find current` bit. Don't put it on a separate line, unless you use ( ) to enclose it.

Comment: The  problem is the If %hours% LSS 10 statement - does not error out and it does not get executed -

Comment: When I ran the script, I changed the `ECHO` lines and put a `PAUSE` after every command. The line that is failing for me is `for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') `

Comment: Yes, that's the one that failed for me too, @EricS. It's because the do part is on a separate line. Needs to be on the same line or wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you Eric , I had changed my if statement to if %hour% LSS 10 echo "less than 10" else echo "greater or equal to 10"
 and I ended up with an error message stating 'else is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. I will search for this message - THANK YOU for your suggestions / help

Comment: The LSS 10 line should have parentheses round the condition also, like `if (%hour% LSS 10) set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%0%ttrn%.csv`

Comment: Thank you both - I do have the do part on the same line in my bat file ManoDestra - I apologize if my question /code was not posted properly and it mislead you -

Comment: Strip your file down to its bare essentials and echo the expected result of each line just using simple echo commands immediately after each line. You'll get through it and debug it quickly using that method :)

Comment: THANK YOU very much  ManoDestra - enclosing the if condition in the parentheses worked.

Comment: Great suggestions from both you - :) - used it and I am ok now -Have a wonderful day

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... I've amended the logic a little to simplify it, particularly that `lss 10` part. And corrected some of the syntactical errors.

```
:: Create the new filename
set tdtd=none
set ttrn=none
set hour=none
set tufn=none

:: get the date and time and then into single variable
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set tdtd=%%k%%i%%j
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set ttrn=%%i%%j

:: get hour If it is less than 10 left pad the hour with a zero
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%h in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set hour=%%h

if (%hour% LSS 10) set ttrn=0%ttrn%
set tufn=\\outgoing\0245_BMS_%tdtd%%ttrn%.csv

copy /Y "\FileName.csv" %tufn%

set tdtd=
set ttrn=
set hour=
set tufn=
:END
```